# How to achieve this Map<String, List<>> structure

Tags: java, data-structures, multimap, multi-mapping

I have data like below:

```
 Key       value
-----      ------
car         toyota
car         bmw
car         honda

fruit       apple
fruit       banana

computer    acer
computer    asus
computer    ibm 
...
```

(Each row of above data is an **object** with fields "key" and "value", all in one List `List<DataObject>`)

I would like to construct the data to a `Map<String, List<String>>` like following:

```
 "car"      : ["toyota", "bmw", "honda"]
 "fruit"    : ["apple","banana"]
 "computer" : ["acer","asus","ibm"]
```

How to achieve above `Map` structure from the data objects?

*********Besides***************

I am more interested in using pure JDK provided classes or interfaces to achieve the result instead of using external library. Any help?

Comment: You've already explained what it should look like (`Map<String, List<String>>`). What do you mean how to achieve it? Also, where and in what format is this data stored?

Comment: @ adarshr , Since the data list has random length(there could be many this kind of data), I need a generic way to construct the Map structure..I am not sure how to do it

Comment: Where/how is this data stored? CSV? Database? XML? JSON?

Comment: @ adarshr, As I mentioned, I already got the data as a list List<DataObject> , each DataObject represent a row with "key" and "value" fields

Comment: You can use ListMultimap from Google Guava collection. http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html

Comment: What external library should I download in order to use this ListMultimap ?

Comment: a good question, and genuinely helpful. i just found what i wanted.  first time i came across Multipmap-s and Guava's LinkedListMultimap. Please reopen this question

Answer (score 35):

```
    Map<String, List<String>> myMaps = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    for (DataObject item : myList) {
        if (!myMaps.containsKey(item.getKey())) {
            myMaps.put(item.getKey(), new ArrayList<String>());
        }
        myMaps.get(item.getKey()).add(item.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: This is worked as a wonder to me. Thank you so much!

Comment: I receive following error: `"DataObject cannot be resolved to a type".`

Answer (score 13):

I would use the guavas `Multimap` implementation. But it is easy doable with the standard JDK aswell.

### Example standard JDK:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(
            "car         toyota\n" +
            "car         bmw\n" +
            "car         honda\n" +
            "fruit       apple\n" +
            "fruit       banana\n" +
            "computer    acer\n" +
            "computer    asus\n" +
            "computer    ibm");

    Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

    while (s.hasNext()) {

        String key = s.next();
        if (!map.containsKey(key))
            map.put(key, new LinkedList<String>());

        map.get(key).add(s.next());
    }

    System.out.println(map);
}
```

### Example guava:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(
            "car         toyota\n" +
            "car         bmw\n" +
            "car         honda\n" +
            "fruit       apple\n" +
            "fruit       banana\n" +
            "computer    acer\n" +
            "computer    asus\n" +
            "computer    ibm");

    Multimap<String, String> map = LinkedListMultimap.create();

    while (s.hasNext()) 
        map.put(s.next(), s.next());

    System.out.println(map);
}
```

---

Output (both implementations):

```
{car=[toyota, bmw, honda], fruit=[apple, banana], computer=[acer, asus, ibm]}
```

Answer (score 6):

```java
Map<String, List<String>> data = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
data.put("car", Arrays.asList("toyota", "bmw", "honda"));
data.put("fruit", Arrays.asList("apple","banana"));
data.put("computer", Arrays.asList("acer","asus","ibm"));
```

Comment: @ scarba05, I only make an example of the data, does not mean the data is like that, actually, the data is quite random, but in that format. If it is as simple as your answer, I won't ask here

Answer (score 5):

The below snippet should help you.

```java
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

ArrayList<String> carList = new ArrayList<String>();
carList.add("toyota");
carList.add("bmw");
carList.add("honda");

map.put("car", carList);

ArrayList<String> fruitList = new ArrayList<String>();
fruitList .add("apple");
fruitList .add("banana");

map.put("fruit", fruitList );
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over the objects. For each object, get its corresponding list from the map. If null, create a new list and put it in the map. Then add the value to the list.

Or Use [Guava's ListMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html), which will do this for you.

Comment: What external library should I download in order to use this ListMultimap ?

Comment: Err... Guava of course. That's why I said Guava's ListMultimap.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
Map<String, List<String>> dataMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Pseudocode:

```
for (String key : keys) {
    if (!dataMap.containsKey(key)) {
        dataMap.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
    }

    dataMap.get(key).add(getValue(key));
}
```

Alternatively, use Guava [`ListMultiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html).